# Follow DRY principle

Tags: if-statement, while-loop, do-while, dry

I have an implementation of following kind-

```
int max_count = 10;

main() {

  Writer writer = //initialise writer;
  List records = new ArrayList();

  while(true) {

    // some functionality
    // some functionality

    if (records.size() >= max_count) {

      // xyz code
      // xyz code

      records = new ArrayList();
    }
  }

  if(records.size() != 0) {

    // xyz code
    // xyz code
  }

}
```

How can I follow the DRY principle here so that the code in while loop and in if block shortens?

Answer (score 1):

You simple have to create another function that contains yout "xyz code" and call it where needed. I hope this answer is what you wanted, if this is not or if you need anything else, feel free to ask !
Have a great day, Lukas.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that but is there any better approach

Comment: I don't think that you can refactor more than that. However, everything depends on the purpose of your code, maybe you can make the loop another way that the code after it is no more needed. Everything depends on the context.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the most simple way would be extracting the xyz code to one function and call it multiple times.

```
int max_count = 10;

void doXyz(){
      // xyz code
      // xyz code
}

main() {

  Writer writer = //initialise writer;
  List records = new ArrayList();

  while(true) {

    // some functionality
    // some functionality

    if (records.size() >= max_count) {

      doXyz()

      records = new ArrayList();
    }
  }

  if(records.size() != 0) {

    doXyz()
  }

}
```

Comment: Any better approach?

Comment: Please define `better`. One could probably rewrite the while loop and the if-condition checks so that there is only one call to doXyz. This would require knowledge about the rest of the program. I think in your case, it would lead to unreadable code. However, because your if-conditions evaluate to true at the same time (one is true if the other one is), you may be able to omit one if-clause.